# How to add a new series by combining two series from a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe `district_df` which contains series Borough such as Bronx, Brooklyn, Manhatten etc. and another series Borough number such as 2, 4, 8 etc.
i want to create another series Board in that dataframe combining Borough and borough number such as 02 Bronx, 04 Brooklyn, 08 manhatten etc,

```
Borough CD Number
Bronx    2
Brooklyn 4 
Manhatten 8
```

into

```
Borough  CD Number    Board
Bronx     2          02 Bronx
Brooklyn  4          04 Brooklyn
Manhatten 8          08 Brooklyn
```

Comment: @yatu - plus1, if check text there is `08 manhatten`

Comment: Yes I think its just OPs error when specifying expected output @jez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) for the concatenation and fill the `CD Number` with the required amount of zeros using [`str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
df['Board'] = df['CD Number'].astype(str).str.zfill(2).str.cat(df.Borough, sep=' ')    

      Borough     CD Number    Board
0      Bronx          2        02 Bronx
1   Brooklyn          4      04 Brooklyn
2  Manhatten          8      08 Manhatten
```

Comment: thanks, I sure will. I have another related question if you don't mind can you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57656404/how-to-join-two-dataframe-by-picking-couple-of-column-from-each-if-one-of-the-co