# how to join two dataframe by picking couple of column from each if one of the column has same data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

there are two dataframes `df_one` and `df_two` I want to create a new data frame by with selective column from each of the dataframes

```
df_one
e b c d 
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8 
6 2 4 8 
9 2 5 6
```

and

```
df_two

e f g h
1 8 7 6 
5 6 6 4 
6 6 2 4 
9 5 3 2
```

I want to create a new dataframe new_df

```
e b g h d
1 6 7 6 4
5 2 6 4 8
6 2 2 4 8
9 2 3 2 6
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnZY1.png)

Comment: What is the criteria you're using?

Comment: the series e is same in both the data and values are both int and strings

Comment: What about `c` and `f`?

Comment: don't need those in the new dataframe. and variable of e match in both the dataframes but they may not be in the same sequence all the value of e from df_one is in e of df_two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 result = pd.merge(df_one, df_two, on='e')
 result=result.loc[:,["e","b","g","h","d"]]
```

Comment: can we sort for values in e

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
pd.merge(df1[["e", "b", "d"]], df2[["e", "g", "h"]], on="e")
```